# iPhone 7 can't hear caller and caller can't hear me

Tags: iphone, audio

I tried to do the new update (iOS 11.2 I believe) on my iPhone 7. that was when it basically went kaput. it first wouldn't go to "sleep" when I would hold it to my ear to talk. so I did a hard reset on it. wouldn't come back on until it died and I plugged it in the next day. made a call to my husband, he couldn't hear me and I couldn't hear him, even when it was on speaker. so I did a hare reset again; same thing. it wouldn't come back on for a few hours. I've connected it to iTunes but it won't do anything that I haven't already tried.
NOW I can't hear any phone calls and they can't hear me even when it's on speaker. the volume works fine and music plays just fine as well. I tried to voice memo app but it won't even say its recording. 
I don't want to have to do another hard reset on my phone and risk having it not come back on permanently.
what do I do from here?

Comment: Have you tried using EarPods?

Comment: Also, is the volume turned up fully when you're on the calls? That goes for both handset and EarPod volume.

Comment: Go to a service and have a look or wait for the next iOS update, it is probably a soft error. Try to restore it from iTunes using the computer, but be careful to do a backup before. It is risky anyway, i lost some of my data, but it should repair all the problems.

Comment: This won’t let me post under anything besides ‘Answer’ I actually don’t have an answer, more of relating to the same problem and looking for a solution....
I had the same exact problem. I reset and it took hours before coming back on it just stayed on the apple sign, and eventually turned back on on its own. Then again, it started freezing, and people would call and I would answer but it would keep ringing, they couldn’t hear me and I couldn’t hear them still.

Comment: I Had a friend do a hard reset it by computer and after restoring to manufacture settings and hours later it turned on finally! But again, when I get a call, it keeps ringing even after being answered, and they still can’t hear me and I can’t hear them, or even with speakers on or headphones.

Comment: I did a complete restore as a new phone. Erased all. Only thing I kept was my phone number. Still have the same problem and it's getting worse. Conclusion: it's either the SIMM card or a hardware issue. Other sites indicate it's a hardware issue.

Answer (score 2):

Hello everyone that has IPhones7 and you can’t hear people calling you just went to T-Mobile got fixed it’s your SIM card needs be replaced and you keep you same phone number